# В HTML значения атрибутов можно не оборачивать в кавычки?

Tags: html, html5, спецификация

В спецификации я заметил записи вот такого вида:

```
<form action="/find.cgi" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type=text name=t>
 <input type=search name=q>
 <input type=submit>
</form>
```

Получается значения можно не оборачивать в кавычки, если они не содержат спец. символов.

Но где прописана эта возможность?

[html.spec.whatwg.org](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/)

Comment: Можно, но лучше оборачивать

Comment: @andreymal почему же?

Comment: Потому что ты не сможешь поставить пробел, оно посчитает, что это ещё один атрибут (`value="Моя надпись"` => `Моя надпись` ; `value=Моя надпись` => `Моя`)

Comment: @Yuri Про пробелы понятно. В остальном очень удобно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, все верно. В спецификации говорится о трех вариантах записи значений атрибутов:

[Вот здесь](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attributes-2)

Конкретно про запись без кавычек, говорит вот эта часть:

> ### Unquoted attribute value syntax
>
> The attribute name, followed by zero or more space characters, followed by a single U+003D EQUALS SIGN character, followed by zero or more space characters, followed by the attribute value, which, in addition to the requirements given above for attribute values, must not contain any literal space characters, any U+0022 QUOTATION MARK characters ("), U+0027 APOSTROPHE characters ('), U+003D EQUALS SIGN characters (=), U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN characters (<), U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN characters (>), or U+0060 GRAVE ACCENT characters (`), and must not be the empty string.
>
> ---
>
> *In the following example, the value attribute is given with the unquoted attribute value syntax:*
>
> ```
> <input value=yes>
> ```
>
> ---
>
> If an attribute using the unquoted attribute syntax is to be followed by another attribute or by the optional U+002F SOLIDUS character (/) allowed in step 6 of the start tag syntax above, then there must be a space character separating the two.

Где сказано что значение не должно содержать пробела, двойных и одинарных кавычек, грависов, треугольных скобок. И это относится не только к значениям без кавычек.

Т.е. значение без кавычек может содержать все те же значения что и обычно. 
Запись из вашего примера можно записать и так:

```
<form action=/find.cgi method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
 <input type=text name=t>
 <input type=search name=q>
 <input type=submit>
</form>
```

Comment: ну можно же было скопировать текст, и вставить как цитату, а не картинкой

Comment: @Grundy В следующий раз так сделаю :)